# Specifying specific path with Express

Tags: javascript, express

I'm having trouble getting my .get() to work.  My understanding of .use() vs .get() is that .use() is used for paths we want to apply things to, while .get() is more specific (choosing specific urls to apply to)

In my example, I want to show 'Applies to all pages' to any page number, but if I type in '/28', I want the .get message to show up instead.  Right now, I get the .use message even when I go to /28.

```
router.use('/:id', function(req, res){
   console.log("Things " + Date.now());
   res.send('Applies to all pages ' + req.params.id);

});


router.get('/28', function(req, res){
   res.send('Secret 28 page');
});
```

Comment: use is for the whole app, and get is for one specific api, which means get path will be appended to use path. For example, your code will match path '/{some_id/28}' to your get method. If you want to respond to anything with 'Applies to all pages' with 28 as the only exception, just make a if statement in you get('/:id', () => { if 28 do something, else do something }) and get rid of use, use will be '/' by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `use` method is used to employ all the `http` verb to certain `path` from your express `app` or express `router`. You have to consider the precedence while using `use`. Here, what is happening is that you have already employed `use` in your dynamic router as `router.use('/:id', ...)` which will take `get` request as well.

You can employ the `get` router first, so that it only take `get`request in `/28` and transfer all the unhandled request to other path.

```
router.get('/28', function(req, res){
   res.send('Secret 28 page');
});

router.use('/:id', function(req, res){
   console.log("Things " + Date.now());
   res.send('Applies to all pages ' + req.params.id);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router.use):

> The order in which you define middleware with router.use() is very important. They are invoked sequentially, thus the order defines middleware precedence.

In your example your `'/:id'` will take precedence when matching.

So swap the order to fix your example, and in general, define more specific handlers first.

Answer (score 1):

Try switching the order of your .get and use.
ExpressJS goes in sequential order when executing. Read this post for more clarification: 
https://derickbailey.com/2016/05/09/in-what-order-does-my-express-js-middleware-execute/

Also, a little unrelated but you can use the .get middleware first, and pass the next step using a third parameter to your callback which is next(), if you haven't known that already.

Answer (score 1):

`.use()` applies to all the paths regardless of HTTP verb, so in your case it applies to GET, POST, PUT and all the other requests that start with `/:id` path and `app.get("/28")` is such a request